# rails deployment not working on port 5000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

Hi I am trying to deploy a rails application on linux. I have configured everything in my app and then I have configured app.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xx.xx.xx.xx   /ip of my server
ServerAlias xx.xx.xx.xx  / ip of my server
ServerAdmin user@localhost
DocumentRoot /myapp/current/public
RailsEnv testing
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/myapp/current/public">
    Allow from All
    Options -MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And my app is running fine when I go to xx.xx.xx.xx , but I change the port 80 to 5000 and go to xx.xx.xx.xx:5000 , app is not running.

Can anyone help me out on this. what I suppose to do ?

Comment: What is the version of your apache? Did you modified host file? Are you on windows, linux or mac?

Comment: Did you config your apache to support Ruby?

Comment: Or your are using rubys internal server

Comment: apache: 2.4.7 . I did not change apache host file, but I modifies my app.conf file to port 5000, I am using ubuntu. And app is working fine when I am using port 80 . Its not ruby internal server, I have a box with ip xx.xx.xx.xx , and on this machine I am runnning my app

Comment: You might be having a firewall problem with ubuntu. You could be having a closed port.can you see localhost:5000?

Comment: What does `curl -v YOUR_IP:5000` say? What's the output of `netstat -ntlpa | grep 5000`?